# CasperJS: querystring as an argument is not working

Tags: javascript, command-line-arguments, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using casperjs and its not working while passing url which has some querystrings like `https://www.google.co.in/imghp?ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tab=wi&ei=ne6FUuvXIIiPrgeN-YGQDA&ved=0CAMQqi4oAg`. I am using the below command to run the script.

`casperjs url.js https://www.google.co.in/imghp?ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tab=wi&ei=ne6FUuvXIIiPrgeN-YGQDA&ved=0CAMQqi4oAg`

**url.js**

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
pageSettings: {
    loadImages:  false,        
    loadPlugins: false         
},
verbose: true,
logLevel: "debug"
});
casper.echo("### Has URL: "+casper.cli.has(0));
casper.echo("### URL: "+casper.cli.get(0));
casper.run();
```

and **Output** of the above script

```
C:\casperjs>casperjs custom.js https://www.google.
co.in/imghp?ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tab=wi&ei=ne6FUuvXIIiPrgeN-YGQDA&ved=0CAMQqi4oAg | cl
ip
### Has URL: true
### Store URL: https://www.google.co.in/imghp?ie=UTF-8
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://www.google.co.in/imghp?ie=UTF-8, HTTP GET

[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.google.co.in/imghp?ie=UT
F-8, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://www.google.co.in/imghp?ie=UTF-8"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2 https://www.google.co.in/imghp?ie=UTF-8 (HTT
P 200)
### Got Url: https://www.google.co.in/imghp?ie=UTF-8 Data, Processing...
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2: done in 908ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 2 steps in 912ms
'hl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'tab' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'ei' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'ved' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\casperjs>
```

Actually its splitting the url after the `&` symbol please give me some solution for it and let me khow if am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to Command Prompt misinterpreting the input.

Running the following should work:

```
casperjs url.js "https://www.google.co.in/imghp?ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tab=wi&ei=ne6FUuvXIIiPrgeN-YGQDA&ved=0CAMQqi4oAg"
```